# Can the owner of a question undelete it with their vote alone? Can they undelete it many times?

Tags: bug, status-completed, undelete

I understood that in order to delete or undelete, you need the votes of three 10k+ users. If the person who votes to undelete it is the owner, can they do it with just their vote alone?

([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2339363/revisions) is the question I am referring to; it will probably be deleted again by the time you see this.)

Is it possible to undelete a question many times? I tried undeleting a question 3 times, it works.

[image]

Comment: To be clear, all sub-10K users cannot cast any undelete vote, not even on their own question, right?

Comment: @smci I think they can; I just did on a beta site (where the limit should be 2K).

Comment: @gerrit: Uh, what, exactly? You undeleted your own question, or merely managed to cast an undelete vote, with 2K rep? or sub-2K rep? on a beta site? Who originally deleted it: you (as a test), or someone else?

Comment: I cast a vote to undelete my own question, which was deleted by the Community user due to being 35 days old and having score -1.  I have 1987 rep on the site, access to moderator tools comes with 2k.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**This has been changed.**

If a post was deleted by users other than its owner, the owner's undelete vote will no longer instantly undelete - it will be counted just like other users' votes to undelete.

Note that if a moderator participated in the deletion, only another moderator can undelete.

Comment: Has this been changed for answers as well?

Comment: Yes, questions and answers share this same behavior.

Answer (score 7):

If the question is deleted by the owner, they can un-delete it immediately. No voting required.

But, when a question is "closed" (the democratic 5-votes-to-close variety), it is then eligible for *true* deletion buy 10K/Moderator voting.

To answer your question, **a user cannot (and *should* not be able to) undo a democratically voted action**. When it takes three users to vote-to-delete a question, it should take three users to vote-to-un-delete a question. The original author should not have any more power than the one-man-one-vote in this case.

Comment: The "immediately" could be many hours?

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't want to test this but, once you delete a question, there is no easy way to get back to it. Maybe if you save the URL somewhere? Someone please verify. But, if you can get back to it, you *should* be able to un-delete it.

Answer (score 3):

If an answer is "deleted by owner" then it can be undeleted by that owner (alone) too. I assume its the same for questions, I never tried.

Comment: Yes, if deleted by owner, you can un-delete immediately.

Answer (score 2):

If I delete my own question I should then be able to un-delete with fair ease. However, if the question is voted by multiple users to delete, an equal (if not greater) number of votes should be required to un-delete.