# What's the point of voting to delete if the poster can just undelete it?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, deleted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question owner able to undelete question that was not self-deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60717/question-owner-able-to-undelete-question-that-was-not-self-deleted)

For example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309354/fastest-php-memory-cache-hashtable/7309394#7309394) was deleted, but the OP just [undeleted it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7309394/revisions). (The links are for 10k users.) I suppose this is by-design, but if that's the  case, wouldn't it be easier if we just flag the post for moderator attention instead?

Comment: I can't see the history you are linking. BTW did you read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean there are cases where you can undelete, but there are exceptions.

Comment: If you disagree with a post you can just downvote it. Also voting to delete it (twice!) just because of disagreement with the authors opinion (however retarded) is privilege abuse.

Comment: @mario I didn't vote (twice) to delete it because I disagree with their opinion. I voted (twice) to delete because it's offensive **and** wrong.

Comment: In such cases I would consider it best to flag. (Can't agree on the "offensive". That answer mostly qualifies as "stupid".) - There was a discussion on this, and iirc it advised to being conservative with deletevotes when they're immediate.

Comment: @mario So it just goes back to the question I am asking. Should we just flag these posts instead? If so, what's the point of the vote to delete feature?

Comment: I would have flagged that. Specifically after the original author undeleted it. Which I believe is his right, if he wants to keep the downvotes. Deletion on answers is a last resort measure, specifically to protect users from more harm, or for spam posts, or illegal submissions (maybe copy&pasted code), etc. The main reason for introduction were useless "thank you posts" however. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69989/propose-a-new-20k-reputation-privilege

Answer (score 2):

It's a pretty rare case where a user will actually undelete an answer of his that's been deleted.  Also, even the community can't undelete something a moderator has deleted, let alone the individual user.

The reason the OP is allowed to undelete his answer, is that he may self-delete his answer, and then edit it into shape (he may have found a mistake, which has happened to me) and then he can undelete it.

Comment: I think unless it is locked, we can vote to undelete any post. BTW the post in my question is an answer.

Comment: No, if a moderator deleted it, you can no longer vote to undelete it.  You used to be able to, but not anymore.  Fixed to reflect answers only.