# Delete votes from users who later become moderators shouldn't prevent community undeletion

Tags: bug, status-review, moderation, vote-to-delete

If you vote to undelete a post that was deleted by a moderator, you will get the message

> A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted

Interestingly, this extends to posts that a user voted to delete prior to becoming a moderator. For example here's a question that is in that state.

[image]

The reverse can also happen. Once a user is no longer a moderator, posts that the moderator bindingly deleted become available to be undeleted.

For example, I just voted to undelete this answer and it worked fine

[image]

Comment: I wonder if the Sam closure played any part in it?

Comment: Sam's closure is irrelevant here. There are plenty of questions like this that were deleted by someone before they became a moderator, but now cannot be undeleted because a moderator deleted them.

Comment: When implementing the lock, Jarrod [commented in April 2011](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77107/lock-posts-by-default-when-deleted-by-a-moderator#comment212853_86481): *"we check the mod election table to see if the deletion happened during the mod's reign of terror, er tenure :)"* So something has changed, or one of the other deleters was a moderator at the time?

Comment: Arjan - My name is the last on the list, and I have certainly never been a moderator.

Comment: @Arjan Well, he *had* nominated to be a moderator at that point, maybe the system decided it was inevitable ;)

Comment: @Arjan I added [another comment here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77107/lock-posts-by-default-when-deleted-by-a-moderator#comment524140_86481), detailing that I have no idea what I was talking about.  Perhaps I meant to change the code after our conversation, but it never happened.

Comment: @JarrodDixon so is this a bug?

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter we're still discussing it, as it could very well be that this "moderator deletes a post, it can't be undeleted" is no longer necessary (it was instituted to prevent post owners from one-click undeleting their content after a mod removed it - [this change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105300/3) would still prevent such behavior).

Comment: @JarrodDixon There are times we don't want a post undeleted by members of the community. Think: the egregious "What's your favorite programming X" examples.

Comment: Hi @GeorgeStocker, what about just using a lock?

Comment: @jmort253 locked and deleted ? Not sure if a question can be in both states.

Comment: @JarrodDixon any updates regarding your discussion, three months later? :)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Community-deleted spam gets locked and deleted, so it's certainly possible.

Comment: I've recently run into the converse problem: being unable to undo an action taken by a _former_ moderator that was done while he was a moderator.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Every question state is combinable, apart from multiple post-notices, close-reasons, lock-types etc. (which aren't separate states).

Answer (score 103):

No, I don't (personally) believe all **previous** actions of a user should become "Moderator actions" (capital 'M') once they gain that diamond ♦.

From 1-reputation upward, everyone on this site is earning increasing abilities to perform various "moderator actions." The whole site is based on community ***self***-moderation. But when a moderator earns that diamond ♦, they explicitly become *deputized* with a few additional abilities not awarded to anyone else (let's call them *"official"* actions, for lack of a better word).

You wouldn't want to say that all actions performed before and up to that point become *ex post facto* "official moderator actions." At the time those actions were performed, those users were ***not* bound by the Moderator Agreement**, nor were they privy to the information and abilities the officially-appointed moderators have. Those actions were not, by definition, *official.*

In that same vein, any official actions taken by a moderator ♦ should *not* suddenly become *un-official*, should they relinquish their position.

As for handling these cases, it may be an oversight… a bug… or just one of those pedantic, edge cases not worth devoting the resources to *right now.* That's a discussion for another day.

Answer (score 40):

I agree with Robert. I think there's one important point he didn't mention, though: we were all new users at one point or another, unfamiliar with the special way Stack Exchange does things. Just because someone understands how to make good "Stack-appropriate" choices today doesn't mean he had that same understanding *x* years ago, when he first gained the power to vote to close.

Comment: Plus, many of us close vote differently as moderators. As a regular user, one can afford to be more aggressive in casting those close votes, but as a moderator, I find that I rarely ever take action unless I am 100% without a doubt sure of my decision and am willing to stand by it in chat and metas. I wouldn't want any of my close decisions prior to being a moderator to be considered official.