# Users can undelete their own posts when deleted by reviewers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, vote-to-delete

According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105300/145982):

> If a post was deleted by users other than its owner, the owner's undelete vote will no longer instantly undelete - it will be counted just like other users' votes to undelete.
>
> Note that if a moderator participated in the deletion, only another moderator can undelete.

This doesn't seem to be the case with posts deleted via the review queue. For example, [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9527/how-should-one-set-up-full-disk-encryption-on-openbsd/118192#118192) (Unix 10k only) was [deleted by review](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/45740), but then the answerer [undeleted it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/118192/revisions) single-handedly:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is [by-design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227112). However, author undeletion does [trigger an automatic flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228479) so moderators can look into it and verify if it should be deleted or not.

You're be surprised how many of these auto-flags I dismiss because the post should have never been deleted in the first place, or the post has been improved since deletion and is now a valid post. If I had to guesstimate, I'd say well over half.

Comment: Of course, I'd guess that that's in large part because most people who's posts are deleted through review either don't know that their post was deleted, or don't know that they can undelete it on their own.  If they did, I'd expect the percentages to shift a bit.  As it is the people invested enough to try to get the post undeleted are inherently more likely to have a post with enough value to not be deleted.

Comment: It sounds less "by-design" and more "we really don't want to deal with fixing that unless it turns into a thing", but good find

Comment: Started out mostly B, sorta transitioned to A after I watched the stuff that got undeleted.