# Can I undelete an answer myself if it was deleted via Recommend deletion votes from review?

Tags: support, review, deleted-answers

In the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222) it says:

> Depending on who deleted your post, you may or may not be able to undelete it. If it was deleted by [...] from review (without three trusted users voting to delete): you can undelete it, but doing so will alert moderators

However, a moderator has just informed me that it does not work like this. If any of the reviewers was a trusted user and they used their delete instead of the recommend deletion then the author of the answer can't undelete the answer by themselves. To undelete it would require two more trusted users's votes.

To make it clear there are 3 possible scenarios:

1. Review ends with 3 delete votes by trusted users.
2. Review ends with 4/6 recommend deletion votes and none of them was cast by a trusted user.
3. Review ends with a mix of 1 or 2 delete votes and recommend deletion votes.

My understanding based on the excerpt above is that only in the first case the OP cannot undelete it themselves. In the remaining two situations the answer can be undeleted by the author, but such action would raise a moderator flag.

When can the author of the answer undelete a post deleted via review and has it always been like this?

Comment: This question is asking for specifics which are not covered in the question which is used as a duplicate target here. In other words, it's not a duplicate, at least not of that question.

Comment: I'm ready to do science on Formatting Sandbox, but I'm not sure if I can gather enough users to coordinate the scenario: [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349621/241919), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349622/241919), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349626/241919)

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. You should also let mods know that they should not delete it or decline the flag.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. I cast the last recommend deletion vote on [your formatting sandbox answer's review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/72672). Feel free to try and undelete!

Comment: I could undelete freely for scenario 2 & 3, waiting for mod's response now... however, for scenario 1, looks like the review didn't fulfill the condition :(

Comment: Also, got some replies by a mod (thanks [Tinkeringbell](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/369802)!) on my posts.

Comment: For 1, you did indeed not meet conditions @MetaAndrewT. , it had a combination of delete votes and recommend deletions in the final review task. 2 had only recommend deletions, and 3 a mix of 2 delete votes and 4 recommend deletions votes :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on <s>doing science together</s> a recent experiment:

- For scenario 2 & 3 (at least one/all "recommend deletion" votes): the OP can unilaterally undelete the answer, but an automatic mod flag will be raised as "disputed low-quality review auto flag".
- For scenario 1 (all "delete" votes by trusted users, which was a failed experiment), it should still require 3 "undelete" votes since trusted users cannot "recommend deletion", only vote to "delete".

Further reading: [Why do we let users (of all reputation levels) unilaterally undelete their own posts if deleted from review?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311536)

Comment: If anyone wants to retry scenario 1, I'm ready (just do it again on [my answer again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349621/241919)), but not really sure about the success rate :/

Comment: Scenario number 3 was the most important to me, so I can accept this experiment.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. Was the experiment successful this time?

Comment: @Brahadeesh nah... mixed between deletion and recommend deletion votes again :/ I'll stop it to prevent noise for mods...