# Can a user submit a second answer on the same question after the first was deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I routinely delete one-line answers that are more like throw-away comments. I do leave a comment explaining why, but I don't usually give them a warning because it means I have to check back later if they actually improved the answer. I always assumed that if the user wanted to have a chance at answering the question properly **the user could just submit a new answer**.

**Is that actually possible?** Or is there a system block that will prevent a user from answering a question after one of their answers on it was deleted by a moderator or the community?

I just realised I don't know for sure and can't seem to find any mention of potential blocks, apart from the one preventing them from [undeleting their original post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86481/260382).

Comment: I don't think so.  There is no limit to the number of answers you can post per day, but if your first was deleted (not by you), then why would you post another?  Also, though it's off-topic, you should use "they" in your post to seem neutral.

Comment: @Ollie I thought I did. :| Looks like I missed one pronoun though so appreciate the edit by P.Mort

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a system block that will prevent a user from answering a question after one of their answers on it was deleted by a mod or the community?

No, there is no such block. See e.g. [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312668/295232). Most users either edit the answer (and perhaps flag it) or (more often) give up on the question altogether. An answer 'soft-deleted' from review (by six 'Recommend Deletion' votes) can even be undeleted by the author, though that will raise an automatic moderator flag.

Of course, if they abuse the absence of a block by basically reposting the same answer, that would be a reason (for me) to warn them via a moderator message.

> I don't usually give them a warning because it means I have to check back later if they actually improved the answer.

Incidentally, the new ['Follow Post' feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/295232) is ideal for situations like this. You'll get notified only when they edit the answer, other events are nigh impossible until the answer is undeleted (at which point you can stop following the post).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, in most cases, there's nothing stopping them from posting a new answer.

However, there are two cases where they may be impeded:

- If they had a past history of posting negatively-received or deleted answers, they may be subject to an automatic answer ban, which would stop them from posting another answer.
- If the question has a prior history of spam answers or deleted answers from new users, and the user's reputation is less than 10, the deletion of the answer may cause the question to be automatically protected by the system, which would stop them from posting another answer unless they earn 10 reputation from a different post first. (If the question is popular and other new users are also answering it, their merely posting the first answer may also cause it to be auto-protected.)