# What should I do if I deleted all my bad low quality unanswered questions and I am permanently blocked from asking and answering questions?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I deleted all my bad low quality unanswered questions and they are unrecoverable, so I am unable to fix or improve my bad low quality unanswered questions.

I am also **permanently** blocked from asking questions and answering questions, so I have no way to contribute to the community in any way.

Is it a sign that I am doomed forever? I guess that yes I am.

Well I still can use email of someone else if I want to post, but with my email I can't post anymore forever. Is that true? I guess that yes it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you deleted all your bad low quality unanswered questions then [you should always be able to undelete them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43943/215590).

Consequently, I see no reason why you should consider them to be unrecoverable.

Once you are satisfied that you can undelete those questions, by testing one first, follow all of these instructions:

[What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997)

I would advise strongly against using another email address to try and circumvent a question/answer ban because that will only deepen the level at which the ban applies.  I recommend reading and acting upon the instructions above instead.

Note that you can always undelete your own questions, but if they were deleted more than 60 days ago [you may not be able to find them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341878/list-of-all-deleted-questions-not-only-recent-ones).  If you suspect that some of these are keeping you in your question ban I think your best option is to ask the moderators of your site to provide you with links to them.

Comment: I have already read it.

Comment: "_If you deleted all your bad low quality unanswered questions then you should always be able to undelete them._" Theoretically that's true, but they need to find the questions first, which isn't always obvious due to [this issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341878/4284627).