# If I am permanently blocked from asking and answering questions and I edited one of my low quality bad questions and changed everything

Tags: discussion, edits, questions, post-ban

If I am permanently blocked from asking and answering questions and I edited one of my low quality bad questions and changed **everything**, including subject, topic, caption, title, body, context and etc and now it is a completely different new question and this question appears to be "good" question.

Will this increase my reputation and allow me to ask and answer questions again?

**EDIT:** I am **NOT improving** the existing question, but **changing** the existing question.

I think that these two actions are **different**.

**Improving** a question means that the topic is **unchanged**, but other things, like grammar, details and etc so the question is more readable, understandable and attractive but with the same topic. After improving this is still the same question.

**Changing** a question means that the topic is **different** and this is **not** the question that was asked from first place. Everything changed, the title, body, context and etc. After changing this is a different question.

Am I wrong? In English "improving" doesn't mean that I can change everything necessarily. Can in improving an existing question I can change everything, so the question is different. Can improving an existing question change the topic of the question?

Comment: [This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) explains everything.  You stated that [you have read it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299965/what-should-i-do-if-i-deleted-all-my-bad-low-quality-unanswered-questions-and-i#comment974757_299966).  Why then are you asking a question which is already answered by the post you supposedly read?

Comment: I read it and I did**n't** find there the answer to this question. I think that there is **difference** between **improving**, but **topic** is **un**changed, and **changing** a question with **different** topic **un**related to the previous question before the edit.

Comment: I see that I have misinterpreted what you meant; as far as I am aware that is considered a form of vandalism, and is not acceptable here.

Comment: Aha I understand.

Comment: Is my question, after edit to clarify everything, still considered as duplicate?

Comment: @ErezZrihen - Yes, your question is still a duplicate, because the solution to a question ban is always the same.  You alter enough of your existing questions (even if they are deleted) so they become acceptable or you wait 6 months.

Comment: "Is it appropriate to edit my bad question and change everything?" would not be considered a duplicate of the linked post, but that's not really what you're currently asking (see your title and "Will this increase my reputation and allow me to ask and answer questions again?"). You might want to edit this question and change everything so you focus on the appropriateness of doing this instead of making it seem like you're wondering how to get a ban lifted, which is a duplicate. Also, making more than 1 or 2 individual words in text bold hinders readability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you think that the question is now good, and the community agrees using its upvotes, then that will certainly help towards lifting your question ban.

I am not sure that it will help with the answer ban too.  I think you need to improve answers for that.

The more questions and answers that you improve, the more likely it is that you will no longer be question or answer banned.

I would not recommend improving just one question if you want to get out of, and stay out of, question and answer bans.

When you improve a Stack Exchange question with a total swap out of content that can mean:

- asking the same question but in a totally different way, which does not invalidate any existing answers; or
- asking a different question that may invalidate existing answers and invite rollback to negate the improvement.

Swapping out the content is most likely to be seen as an improvement if there are no existing answers to invalidate.

I recommend always thinking carefully before asking/editing any question on a Stack Exchange site because its content is continually being assessed by the site's users who are encouraged to use their upvotes and downvotes to assess its current state.

Comment: The OP isn't suggesting they would _improve_ the question, but _change it into a completely new question_.

Comment: @Daedalus **exactly**. You now understand what I am really asking. Of course that I can**not** completely change the answer to question, because it must be related to question. In answer I must **improve** it, but **not** changing it.

Comment: @Daedalus Changing it into a different question (if it gets net upvoted as a result) would certainly be seen as an improvement.  If it already has an answer addressing the original question then changing to a different question would invite a rollback.

Comment: rollback? What that means?

Comment: @ErezZrihen Return to the state before the edit.

Comment: And I will have **no** choice, but really **improving** it, but **not** changing it.

Comment: If you vandalize your own question it will be reverted to a previous revision

Comment: revision? And if the question is bad then the changes are canceled. But if the question is good then the changes are applied. Correct?

Comment: @ErezZrihen - If you vandalize your own questions, a question ban, will be the least of your worries.  Unless you plan to do that question will not be reverted to an earlier revision.  Of course if your question happens to have an answer already, and you change the question so the answer is no longer relevant, the question will be reverted and likely locked to prevent further modification.

Answer (score 7):

I suppose you're talking about what you did to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17483609/4284627):

[image]

You're not changing the question, you're deleting it's content and replacing it with nonsense. That's vandalism and is not acceptable, and your edit got correctly rolled back. Doing that will definitely not lift your question ban, on the contrary, it will attract more downvotes and therefore not do anything against your ban. It will even make it even more difficult for you to get out of your ban. Even if the vandalism is rolled back, you will keep the downvotes, so this is not a good idea. And if you do that too much, you will get suspended, that's what happened to a Stack Overflow user whose name I won't post here.

Otherwise, if you edit your question into a good, on-topic question, even if you change what you're actually asking, then yes, your question will get upvotes and reopen votes. Hopefully, it will get enough of them to give it a positive score and to reopen it, it which case it will help you get out of your question ban.

But if you're question banned, it's because you asked a lot of bad questions, so editing only one of them won't do you much good. I suggest you edit as many of them as you can. But is seems like you have a lot of deleted questions and they also count towards the ban, so if you can, undelete them and edit them. I'm aware that that isn't always possible due to [this issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341878/4284627), there's unfortunately nothing you can do about it, that's just the system that is badly made. They say that you can only see a list of your recently deleted posts because they don't want you to be stuck regretting bad questions you've asked years ago ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272542/4284627)), but that doesn't make any sense since those questions still count against the question ban. All you can do is undelete and edit the questions that you can find, and hope that that's enough. If it's not, [you will be given a second chance in 6 months](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans). Use that time to look around on Meta and in the help center to learn how to ask good questions if you haven't done that already (I recommend you do that anyway).

Comment: "And if you do that too much, you will get suspended, that's what happened to this user." You shouldn't be calling out specific users :/

Comment: I have forgotten about the existence of the deleted question shown in the image. I also have **NO** interest in this question anymore, because I have found myself the answer to this question years ago and now I even have Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise installed on my computer, so I leave this question forever and I do**n't** want to get reminded about it. Getting reminded about this terrible question causes me pain emotionally. In changing a question I do delete it's content, but **NOT** necessarily replacing it with nonsense. I did**n't** do that with the question you show me in the image.

Comment: That's exactly how the question in the image was posted first time in Stack Overflow. I did**n't** had the idea to replace it's content with other content and changing the topic in that time. I still hope that this terrible question that I ca**n't** see it anymore will, physically, get deleted from the hardisk of the servers in the network or from the database forever. If I could change the past, which I ca**n't**, but if I could I would prevent myself from asking this question in the first place. I am **not** stopping blameing myself that I asked this question.I am so regretting that I did it

Comment: I am so sorry that I asked this terrible question.

Comment: @DavidPostill That's true, I edited to remove the link to the user's profile.

Comment: @ErezZrihen If you don't want to get associated with that specific question, you can request to have it [dissociated from your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732/349538), but you should do that only because you don't want your name associated with it, not to get around the question ban. I suggest you read [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225997/349538) about post dissociation and the question ban.

Comment: @DonaldDuck "not to get around the question ban" that was **not** attempt to get around the question ban. I have already understood that the only way to get around the question ban is to either improve my existing questions or change them to different good question if this wo**n't** invalidate existing answers. I am also about logging out and quitting Stack Exchange and all it's networks forever for good. I prefer to find the answers to my questions by google only on the hard way.